# vaadin, getting null pointer when trying to add item to sqlContainer

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm very new to vaadin ( and to java).

i have an table that has an SQLcontainer like so :

```
public class ProjectTable extends Table {
      public ProjectTable(final DocumentmanagerApplication app) {
          setSizeFull();
          setContainerDataSource(app.getDbHelp().getProjectContainer());
          setImmediate(true);

          commit();
          setSelectable(true);

      }
    }
```

i have a button and a TextField , to fill data in the table

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        SQLContainer cont = h.getAssetContainer();
        String dataResult = tf.getValue().toString(); // TEXT FIELD 
        System.out.println(dataResult);






        Object itemId = cont.addItem(); // cont is the container
        **cont.getContainerProperty(itemId , "id").setValue(dataResult);      // BUG IS HERE !!! **  


try {
            cont.commit();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i keep getting a " null pointer exception" no matter what i do. on the line **cont.getContainerProperty(itemId , "id").setValue(dataResult);

am i doing anything wrong ? and what is null pointer ?

please inform me if anything was unclear.

please help , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression returns `null`:

```
cont.getContainerProperty(itemId , "id")
```

And then you try to invoke a method on `null`. This causes the `NullPointerException`. So have a look, *why* the container does not provide a non-null value for the key at the time you invoke it.

Comment: container.getContainerPropertyIds also has null pointer issue. :( i dont have any clue why is that or what is going on. however. itemId is not null , (checked it ).

Comment: The container doesn't contain the item "itemId" *or* the object "itemId" doesn't have a property `id`. That's the rule to return `null`. `getContainerPropertyIds` should not return null but an empty list (at worst case).

Answer (score 4):

BTW, if you have a Vaadin Table and you applied a Filter to it, you need to remove it before, if not probably you will get a null pointer exception in the getContainerProperty(itemId, property) method

Comment: Its right. Filter will not allow the item to add. Although `container.addItem()` will return you an `itemId` but actually if you observe , the size of container won't change. As a solution you can temporally `removeContainerFilter` and then `addItem` and then `addContainerFilter` again.